# HV Rectifier output for APD biasing

Tags: high-voltage, rectifier, photodiode, biasing

I am trying to convert low 5V or 12V to -200V using this device. Which converts it using transformer and rectifier at the output:
[image: 5V to 200V converter]

Can I just attach HV OUT to bias APD detectors? Or is there any special technique to attach it to photodiode. Because without resistive load output is not regulated, as it's load dependent voltage source. I just cannot wrap my head around photodiode load.

Comment: Let me suggest an easier approach: buy a ready-made DC-DC converter. For example: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/xp-power/QH02-5/5873649

Comment: @DavideAndrea, thanks for reply. QH02-5 is also unregulated supply or load-dependent supply. Basically transformer+rectifier. My circuit is actually taken from https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/xp-power/AH02P-5/5873540. So question remains. Is that can we attach APD for biasing